# Close apache derby connection using standard java.sql.Connection

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I am currently developing a program that can be used with different databases (at the moment I'm testing with an embedded Derby and MySQL).

Is it possible to free the Derby database (let another process use it) from my application without using something derby specific? I know that this could be done by appending `shutdown=true` to the jdbc url but that is something that I would like to avoid. I've tried with `connection.close()` but it didn't work.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you need more than one process to access your Derby database, you should stop using the embedded version an switch to using a [Derby Network Server](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ns_intro.html).  This will start Derby so it is accessible in the familiar client / server fashion.  In this mode, Derby will be accessible by multiple, simultaneous connections.  This is analogous to what you are all ready doing with MySQL.

Comment: I know that would be the best option but I'm modifying a desktop java application that is already deployed in many customers computers so it would not be possible to change all the databases.

Comment: I've resolved it by making the other process wait until the connection is closed.